# Sending an intent when a pop up menu item is selected

Tags: android, android-intent, popupmenu, startactivityforresult

I'm trying to change the background colour of a main activity when an item from a pop up menu in a sub-activity is selected. However, when I run the app and choose said item, the app crashes. This is the sub-activity code:

```
public class Modify extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button, submit;
EditText edit;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.modify);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(Modify.this, button);
            pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,pop.getMenu());
            pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Modify.this, MainActivity.class);
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.red:
                            i.putExtra("color","red");
                            break;

                        //TODO add more colours

                        default:
                            return false;

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            pop.show();
        }
    });


    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String message = edit.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", message);
            setResult(2, intent);
            finish();
        }

    });

  }
}
```

I'm not really sure if the intents I declare on each case are actually getting back to the changeBackground method in the Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//GLOBALS
TextView txt;
Button btn;
RelativeLayout rel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn);
    rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String color = intent.getStringExtra("color");
    changeBackground(color);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //ON CLICK SETS INTENT
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Modify.class);

            //INTENT STARTS ACTIVITY 2
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        //SET TEXT WHEN RESULT IS ACCEPTED
        String message = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
        txt.setText(message);

    }

}

public void changeBackground(String color) {

    if (color.equals("red")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (color.equals("green")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (color.equals("blue")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `startActivityForResult()` ? Show the logcat too

Comment: I have a startActivityForResult() for the text extra. However, could I set the background colour of the main activity with intents from a sub activity that send extras to be passed as arguments for the changeBackground method?

Comment: Check my answer below please.

Comment: Please check my full code. Maybe it will clarify what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just use startActivityforResult(intent);

Comment: I may have phrased my question incorrectly. I am attempting to set the colour of the main activity with intents on each item from a pop up menu whilst also sending a text extra as an onActivityResult from a separate button. Both of these views are on a sub activity where you modify the appearance of the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code:

```
botton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(Modify.this, botton);
            pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,pop.getMenu());
            pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Modify.this, MainActivity.class);

                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.red:
                            i.putExtra("color","red");                                                              
                            break;

                        case R.id.magenta:
                            i.putExtra("color","magenta");                          
                            break;

                        default:
                            return false;
                    }

                    startActivity(i);  
                    finish(); 

                    return true;
                }
            });                    
            pop.show();
        }
    });
```

In `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`:

```
String color = getIntent().getStringExtra("color", "red");
    if (color.equals("red")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (color.equals("green")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (color.equals("blue")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it crashes when launched. For some reason as soon as I toggle comment that second code snippet it runs normally but with no action for when I select an item.

Comment: 1) Did you change `onMenuItemClick` to `return true` ?

2) Where did you add the second code snippet ? It should be in `onCreate()` after setContentView`. Please checkout what error you are getting

Comment: Yes. I also have a separate onActivityResult on the main activity which receives a text extra. Maybe I cannot mix both types of intents.

Comment: What is your requirement ? Please clarify. So far I got this:  *You have a Modify activity. On PopPup menu Item selected, It will load MainActivity with background according to the selection.* Isn't this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Main Activity starts activity for result. Sub Activity sets text as result. But additionally I want to set the colour of the Main Activity when an item is selected from a pop up menu by using intents. Finally when I set text as result on click listener with a button on the Sub Activity to return to the Main Activity, I want the Main Activity to have a modified textview and a different relative layout colour.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, a bit inelegantly:

Sub-activity:

```
public class Modify extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button, submit;
EditText edit;
String s;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.modify);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(Modify.this, boton);
            pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, pop.getMenu());
            pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch(item.getItemId()){

                        case R.id.red:
                            s="red";
                            return true;

                        case R.id.green:
                            s="green";
                            return true;

                        case R.id.blue:
                            s="blue";
                            return true;

                        case R.id.yellow:
                            s="yellow";
                            return true;

                        case R.id.magenta:
                            s="magenta";
                            return true;

                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            pop.show();
        }

    });


    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Modify.this,MainActivity.class);
            String message = edit.getText().toString();
            String colorMessage = s;
            i.putExtra("MESSAGE", message);
            i.putExtra("COLOR", colorMessage);
            setResult(2,i);
            finish();
        }

    });

  }

}
```

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn);
    rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Modify.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,2);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==2)
    {

        String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
        txt.setText(message);
        String color = data.getStringExtra("COLOR");
        changeBackground(color);
    }
}
public void changeBackground(String color) {
    if (color.equals("red")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (color.equals("green")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (color.equals("blue")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (color.equals("yellow")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    } else if (color.equals("magenta")) {
        rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    }
 }

}
```

Please let me know if there's a more elegant way to get the colours from the switch cases without having to assign them to a variable on each of them.

Cheers